# Changing the Mediawiki text font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, mediawiki

I'd like to change the font of my wiki, referencing a font that I have installed. I tried to do this user Common.css, but it made no difference.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'vcr';
src: url('http://example.com/vcr.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('http://example.com/vcr.woff') format('woff');}
.mw-body,
.mw-headline,
.mw-label,
.mw-input,
.mw-body-content,
.mw-allpages-table-form,
.mw-allpages-nav {
font-family: 'vcr';}
```

Here's what I have on. I may be doing this completely wrong, but I'm trying to do what it appears so on the Mediawiki site itself. I really don't know how I will be able to do this. I think I've tried editing a body in some css somewhere once but that made things worse. Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding !important after the font-family declaration.

```
font-family: 'vcr' !important;
```

Further info here: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Welp, seems like that and the fact that I forgot to change the url back seems to have fixed it. Thanks.